# Haskell AND gate without using == or /=

Tags: haskell, conditional-statements, expression

I am not allowed to use == or /=, but I have no idea how I can rewrite it without them.

```
iffC x y = 
if x == True && y == True then True
  else if x == False && y == False then True
    else False

iffG x y
  | y == True && x == True = True
  | y == False && x == False = True
  | otherwise = False
```

Comment: How about pattern matching, is that allowed?  My first guess is that's the solution the professor is trying to nudge you towards.

Comment: In what world is AND defined as `xnor`?  Notice that's what you appear to be implementing.  Also notice `if expr then True else False` is just `expr` and `val == True` is a long way to spell `val`.

Comment: The two-argument function iff returns True exactly when both Boolean operands have the same value. Otherwise it returns False. Construct a design recipe for the iff function and implement it using

a) Conditional expressions (iffC). 
b) Guarded equations (iffG).
c) Pattern matching (iffP).

I already did Pattern without == and /= 

`iffP True True = True
iffP False False = True
iffP _ _ = False`

Comment: @Daniel_H So you solved the problem yourself?

Comment: @HenriMenke No, I still have to solve it using Guarded and Conditional without == and /=. I noticed my mistake with XNOR instead of AND and have fixed that. I tried `iffC x y =
  if True True then True
      else False` but that doesnt work

Comment: @Daniel_H You are looking for `iffC x y = if x && y then True else False` which is equivalent to `iffC x y = x && y`.

Comment: Note that you can write `x && y` as `if x then ... else ...` (find what to write in the dots).

Comment: @HenriMenke Thank you so much, everything is perfect now `iffC x y = if x && y then True
  else False

iffG x y
  | x && y = True
  | otherwise = False

iffP True True = True
iffP _ _ = False

iffB x y = x && y` I feel so stupid for not realising this

Comment: It will always be a miracle to me why people think it makes sense to write redundant expressions like `y = if x==True then True else False`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I think it's a natural consequence of imperative habits. You know you need to make a decision based some set of booleans, so you start by writing `if`. Then you figure out what condition to put there, and what goes in the `then` and `else` clauses, and once it works you don't go back and realize that what you did is just silly, because *of course* `if` is how you work with booleans! What else would you use?

Comment: @leftaroundabout Most imperative tutorials focus only on integer variables and expressions. When dealing with `if (guard) ...` they never make you think about the guard being an _expression_ as well, only having a boolean type. They just show examples where integer variables are compared with `<,==,>=,...`. Complex guards use `&&` as if it were a special "guard" syntax than an operator between boolean expressions. That's why you commonly see `if (x==0 && y<4) flag=true; else flag=false;`: there is no such a thing as a boolean expression, only "guard syntax", to be used only inside `if/while`.

Comment: `if x == True then True else False` is just as redundant in imperative code as it is in functional code. As best as I can tell, people just don't recognize that the condition is itself an expression that evaluates to a Boolean value, rather than somehow "part" of the `if` statement itself.  (Related to the shell mistake of thinking that `[ ... ]` is part of the `if` statement rather than a command whose exit status is used by the `if` statement.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could rewrite you existing solutions like this, which I think is what the exercise was aimed at.

```haskell
iffC :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
iffC x y = if x && y
           then True
           else False

iffG :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
iffG x y | x && y = True
         | otherwise = False

iffP :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
iffP True True = True
iffP _ _ = False
```

I don't really see how this exercise is instructive because all those implementations are a complicated way of saying `&&`.

Comment: `... | foo = True | otherwise = False` can be shorted to just `... = foo`. Doing this rewrite in `iffG` leads us back to the same implementation as for `iffC`; therefore I suspect the question about "use a guard" was aiming at something like `iffG x y | x = y | otherwise = False` as the implementation.

Comment: The first two are antipatterns, so I think this is not the intended solution. Also, this implements `&&` instead of iff.

Comment: @chi Well, I don't know the original exercise, but this is what OP presented.  These examples are antipatterns in this case but I guess the exercise was intended to apply all of them without further consideration.  Of course I could be completely wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Any binary boolean operator can be defined using the pattern

```
op :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
op x y =
   if x
   then if y then ... else ...
   else if y then ... else ...
```

where the four `...` are, essentially, the truth table for `op`.

Often this leads to antipatterns like

```
if z then True else False
```

which should be rewritten as

```
z
```

or

```
if z then False else True
```

which should be rewritten as

```
not z
```

or

```
if z then True else True
```

which should be rewritten as

```
True
```

or the analogous case for `False`. Essentially, such `if`s can always be rewritten as one of `z, not z, True, False`.

Answer (score 0):

Pattern matching seems like it would work like a charm for this.

```
iffC :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
iffC True True = True
iffC False False = True
iffC _ _ = False
```

You get the free bonus of having your truth table visible.